MYSQL query para contar relaciones en la misma tabla con multiples group by
Tengo una tabla de logs, para mirar quien trabaja en cada "incidencia", y quiero para cada usuario abridor de incidencias, el número de ordenes cerradas, independientemente de quién cerró cada una y por fecha de cerrado.
El problema reside en que el usuario que la crea (estado_incidencia_id = 1) puede ser que sea el mismo que la cierra (estado_incidencia_id = 2) pero también puede ser que se la traspase a otro usuario en estado de revisión (estado_incidencia_id = 3) y luego este último ya la cierre, también se pueden reactivar, por ello solo me haria falta saber el primer estado de "cerrado".
Ejemplo:

Como podéis ver, el usuario 51 la abre (estado_incidencia = 1), y luego se pasa al 46 para revisión (estado_incidencia = 3) y ya luego este la cierra (estado_incidencia_id = 2). Entonces, para el usuario 51, que la pase al estado 3 se considera para él "cerrada" y la tendría que contar.
Tendría que contar también si el mismo usuario la abre (estado_incidencia = 1) y la cierra (estado_incidencia_id = 2).
Ejemplo:

Lo he intentado con esta query:
SELECT COUNT(b.id) as `count`, a.created_by, DAY(b.fecha) as `filter_day`, MONTH(b.fecha) as `filter_month`
FROM incidencia_status_logs AS a
LEFT JOIN incidencia_status_logs AS b ON a.incidencia_id = b.incidencia_id 
WHERE a.estado_incidencia_id = 1 AND a.created_by = 51
AND (b.estado_incidencia_id = 3 OR b.estado_incidencia_id = 2)
AND b.incidencia_id IS NOT NULL
AND DATE(b.fecha) BETWEEN '2024-06-26' AND '2024-07-25'
GROUP BY `filter_day`, `filter_month`, `created_by` 
ORDER BY created_by, filter_month, filter_day

y tambien con esta:
SELECT COUNT(incidencia_status_logs.id) as `count`, incidencia_status_logs.created_by, DAY(incidencia_status_logs.fecha) as `filter_day`, MONTH(incidencia_status_logs.fecha) as `filter_month` 
FROM `incidencia_status_logs` 
WHERE (
EXISTS 
(SELECT * from incidencia_status_logs t2 
WHERE t2.estado_incidencia_id = 1 AND t2.created_by IN (51)) 
AND EXISTS 
(SELECT * from incidencia_status_logs t2 WHERE t2.estado_incidencia_id = 3 OR t2.estado_incidencia_id = 2)) 
AND DATE(incidencia_status_logs.fecha) between '2024-06-26' AND '2024-07-25'
GROUP BY `filter_day`, `filter_month`, `created_by` 
ORDER BY created_by, filter_month, filter_day

Los resultados serían de este estilo (adjunto img), pero no me cuadran.

Alguna idea? Gracias.

Considero que, más allá de la explicación, que está bien, ayuda a aclarar lo que buscas expresarlo en lenguaje coloquial. Me pregunto si lo que buscas saber es, para cada usuario abridor de ordenes, el número de ordenes cerradas, independietemente de quién cerró cada una? De ser así, ¿vas a agrupar por la fecha de apertura o por la fecha de cierre? (Por favor, responde al [edit] la pregunta y déjame una mención en un mensaje, para ver si con lo que publicas me aclaro para escribir una respuesta. Un saludo.

@jachguate muchas gracias por la respuesta, ya he editado mi pregunta. Disculpa por la ambigüedad, como tú supones quiero saber para cada usuario abridor, el numero de ordenes cerradas por fecha de cierre, independientemente de quien la cierre. Un saludo y gracias!

No te calzan porque, en tu ejemplo, haces un join entre la consulta de incidencias abiertas por el usuario 51, y la consulta de incidencias en estado 2 o 3 que calcen con los IDs de la primera. Para toda incidencia que haya pasado por el estado 2 antes del 3, estarás contando doble. La dificultad, en tu caso, es que no tienes cómo restringir el JOIN para que compare también al usuario. En rigor tu modelo debiera considerar que el usuario 51 es el autor de la incidencia que se ha derivado al usuario 46.

Para resolverlo, lo que propongo es:
Primero, determinar el primer cierre, con su fecha, para cada incidencia. Esto podemos hacerlo con la consulta siguiente:
select incidencia_id, min(fecha) FechaPrimerCierre
  from incidencia_status_logs
 where estado_incidencia_id in (2, 3)
 group by incidencia_id 

Armados con esta información, lo siguiente que tendríamos que hacer es tomar todas las incidencias abiertas y hacer inner join con el resultado anterior. Finalmente, sobre el conjunto resultante, contar los registros agrupando por el campo created_by de la creación de la incidencia y el día y mes de la fecha de cierre.
Para armar la solución final, mi sugerencia es usar un CTE, si tu versión de mySQL lo soporta, pues la consulta es más elegante y fácil de entender:
with
cierre as (
select incidencia_id, min(fecha) FechaPrimerCierre
  from incidencia_status_logs
 where estado_incidencia_id in (2, 3)
 group by incidencia_id 
)
select   apertura.created_by
       , day(cierre.FechaPrimerCierre) dia
       , month(cierre.FechaPrimerCierre) mes
       , count(1) contador
  from incidencia_status_logs apertura
       inner join cierre on cierre.incidencia_id = apertura.incidencia_id
 where apertura.estado_incidencia_id = 1

Debes tener cuidado, pues si hay información de más de un año en la tabla, te va a contar los registros de todos los años para cada día y mes.
También, si hay alguna incidencia que pueda tener más de un registro con estado 1, haría falta definir que pasa en ese caso. Probablemente haya que encontrar la primera apertura, así como se hace con el cierre.
Si tu versión de mySQL no soporta CTE's, puedes escribir la consulta usando una tabla derivada:
select   apertura.created_by
       , day(cierre.FechaPrimerCierre) dia
       , month(cierre.FechaPrimerCierre) mes
       , count(1) contador
  from incidencia_status_logs apertura
       inner join (select incidencia_id, min(fecha) FechaPrimerCierre
                     from incidencia_status_logs
                    where estado_incidencia_id in (2, 3)
                    group by incidencia_id 
                  ) cierre on cierre.incidencia_id = apertura.incidencia_id
 where apertura.estado_incidencia_id = 1

Como puedes ver, la idea es la misma, pero considero que la consulta queda más difícil de leer, y por tanto, de mantener.

Hola, @jachguate he probado tu respuesta pero solo me obtiene 1 row con todas las incidencias para 1 solo usuario...

@Anna, puedes dejar una muestra de la tabla y algunos datos de ejemplo para probarla y corregirla.
